# Extract and Trust certificate via command line in windows

Tags: windows, drivers, certificate, openssl

I am trying to setup a printer via command line in windows. So far I everything is working well except I don't know of any way to extract .cer from .cat via command line.

I could extract it via windows gui and later successfully trust it via certmgr.exe.

So if anyone knows how or can point me in the direction of extracting .cer from .cat using command line.

Comment: Extract the file using the [EXPAND](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744339%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) command.

Comment: Very similar to this [extract certificate from sys file question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36775331/extract-certificate-from-sys-file) - you can use cat file instead of sys file in the powershell script.